# Mute Snapchat's shutter sound

Tags: audio, snapchat

I have Snapchat 10.23.11 on Huawei and my friend has the same version but on a Samsung device. I have muted the system Camera app and in the system app, there's no shutter sound. In Snapchat, when I'm taking a photo using the back camera without a flashlight, there's a shutter sound but my friend on her Samsung device with the same Snapchat version doesn't have a shutter sound.

When I had a Snapchat version from about October 2017, there wasn't a shutter sound. Last few days, I've updated the Snapchat app and all others app and the shutter sound appeared.

What's going on? How to remove the shutter sound?

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that the Snapchat app is taking an actual photo as opposed to a screenshot of the viewfinder which is done on most Android Snapchat devices for compatibility.

However, on some phones like Samsung Galaxy S7, the rear camera makes a shutter sound because it takes an actual photo and not a screenshot of the preview feed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189542/snapchat-shutter-sound-before-update#comment253576_197097),

> The problem is solved, I've installed TWRP and removed camera shutter ogg file.